# How to add red asterisk in label of TextFormField In Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

As we are not able to make widget like RichText/Text Span For styling TextFormField,

Can anyone help me out regarding this...

Now Getting:-

[image]

Expected Result:-

[image]

How we can achieve a result like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way, but not exactly equals:

```dart
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Ciao',
                  suffixText: '*',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Or create a custom `TextField` to use hint as Widget instead of String

You can use my two customized files:

- [input_decorator.dart](https://gist.github.com/andrea689/969653dc4f697b8478d1d167f8d2588f#file-input_decorator-dart)
- [text_field_custom.dart](https://gist.github.com/andrea689/969653dc4f697b8478d1d167f8d2588f#file-text_field_custom-dart)

```dart
              TextFieldCustom(
                hintText: Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'FIRST NAME',
                    children: <InlineSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '*',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ],
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: But when i use your two customized files, validator of TextFiled disappear?

Comment: can you share null safety file

Answer (score 2):

Try these two files I had same requirement.
Just add attribute  `isMandate: true` in CInputDecoration and use CTextField.

```
CTextField(
...
  decoration: new CInputDecoration(
     isMandate: true,
...
))
```

https://github.com/sumit1954/Flutter/blob/master/CInputDecorator.dart
https://github.com/sumit1954/Flutter/blob/master/CTextField.dart

Comment: can you share null safety file

Answer (score 2):

### Place this code in TextFormField or TextField

this label works as an hint property

```
label: RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Full Name',
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey),
      children: [
        TextSpan(
          text: ' *',
          style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      )
    ]
  ),
  floatingLabelBehavior:FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
```

[image: label parameter]

look at above screenshot of label parameter holding a `Widget` not a `String` without any error

Comment: The label param takes a text, not a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this in hard fast way. Replace input_decorator.dart with below code:

https://github.com/neal786y/InputDecoratorForMandatoryFields/blob/master/input_decorator.dart

In your InputDecoration scope add a property "isMandatoryField: true"

Worked for me on temporary basis.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. While your answer may help to achieve what the original poster wants, your post offers no guidance or explanation that may help others seeking a similar solution. Please include more context in your reply, see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: can you share null safety file

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of flutter you can also send a widget in label parameter. So, something like this is possible

```
 label: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(label.replaceAll('*', '')),
          label.contains('*')
              ? Text(
                  '*',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `label` property inside `InputDecorator`
See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209425/8913302